# Visual Studio 2010 DON'T CLEAR Query if doesn't succed or syntax error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database, sql-server

In VS2010 when you perform a query against database if the query itself has any syntax error the VS by default clears all text from screen. This makes you to type again the text and resolve syntax.

I'd like that VS warns you that the query has syntax error, right, but doesn't clear the typed query.

Is is possible?
thank you!!

Comment: Yes- Click on "ignore" and it won't clear the query? or is that SSMS? Yea maybe you should use that as it designed for database maintenance

Comment: No, is the Visual Studio 2010 -> Server Explorer.
I have 4gb RAM. Usually with VS2010 + Chrome + IE8 + Outlook.
Does the SSMS eat much RAM?

Comment: Yes.. Use [SSMS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961)- It can do it whats you askings in the question & more...